# How to add AWS Auth to open api spec?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, openapi, swaggerhub

I am writing API specs for a service that requires AWS auth. But I can't find any information as to how to add this authentication in the specs.  ( What I did find was this: https://support.smartbear.com/swaggerhub/docs/integrations/amazon-api-gateway.html, which seems needs you to integrate with AWS. But I do not want/need any such integration. My API spec is only supposed to be documentation for how a user is supposed to use them.)